# searching and filter array firebase data swift3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchbar

My app crashing while search a text in a searchbar with error: thread1:signal SIGABRT probably the problem updateSearchResults() method?
or type of array? I'm beginner with swift any idea?

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var data = [Any]()
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!

// Filter Data from Firebase
var filteredData = [Any]()

// Declare searchBar

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


//is the device landscape or portrait
var isPortraid = true

@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!



func fetchDataFromFirebase(){
    EZLoadingActivity.show("caricamento...", disableUI: true)
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let dataDict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        self.data = dataDict["data"] as! [Any]
        self.filteredData = self.data
        print ("Sacco di merda:\(self.filteredData)")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        EZLoadingActivity.hide()
    })
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    tableView.delegate = self
    fetchDataFromFirebase()

    //  Implement searchBar
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar




    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.orientationChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)


}


//TableView Data Source and Delegate


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return filteredData.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell", for:indexPath) as! MainScreenTableViewCell
    let rowData = self.filteredData[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let imageName  = rowData["imageName"] as! String
    cell.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    let label = rowData["categoryName"] as! String
    cell.mealCategoryLabel.text = label
    return cell
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let categoryViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoryViewController") as! CategoryViewController
    let rowData = self.data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    categoryViewController.categoryTitle = rowData["categoryName"] as! String
    let categoryData = rowData["category"] as! [Any]
    categoryViewController.data = categoryData
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(categoryViewController, animated: true)

}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if isPortraid {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height/3
    } else {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height/1.2
    }
}
```

//Method for update search

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.searchBar.text! == ""{
        filteredData = data
    } else {
        filteredData = data.filter{($0 as AnyObject).contains(searchController.searchBar.text!)}

    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if searchController.searchBar.text! == ""
```

This is almost certainly the offender.  The `text` property on UI objects is typically nil when it's empty, so when you force unwrap it your app crashes.  You should **never** force unwrap something unless you are **absolutely certain** it will never be nil at that point.

There's a couple different ways you can handle this, which basically amount to making sure `text` isn't nil before you do anything with it.

Personally I would rewrite the if statement to unwrap the optional for the non-empty case:

```
if let text = searchController.searchBar.text, text != "" {
    filteredData = data.filter{($0 as AnyObject).contains(text)}
} else {
    filteredData = data
}
```

You could also use [nil-coalescing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72):

```
if (searchController.searchBar.text ?? "") == ""
```

but personally I prefer to write it to avoid force unwrapping even when you're sure it isn't nil, so I would recommend the first one.